# Update postgressql query not working in h2

Tags: sql, sql-update, h2

I'm trying to execute myquery on h2 console, and i'm getting syntaxe error

```
update deal stdeal set sub_product_type = maxleg.sub_product_type, 
product_type=stdeal.sub_product_type
from ( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY structure_id ORDER BY leg_id DESC) AS rowNumber,
          structure_id, sub_product_type
          from deal
          where product_type = 'structure'
                and sub_product_type not in ('vp', 'premium')
  ) maxleg 
where stdeal.structure_id = maxleg.structure_id
and stdeal.product_type = 'structure'
and stdeal.sub_product_type in ('vp', 'premium')
and rowNumber = 1
```

This query is working fine in pgAdmin,

When I remove the from of maxleg definition, the query work,
The issue is not coming from the `ROW_NUMBER` function, even when I remove this function, I have the same issue, **sql syntax error**.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable PostgreSQL compatibility mode of H2 by appending `;MODE=PostgreSQL` to JDBC URL if you need to use that PostgreSQL-specific syntax (you may also want to add `;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH` for better compatibility).

You also need a some recent version of H2, old versions don't have window functions.

Since PostgreSQL 15 it is possible to use a very powerful standard `MERGE` command instead of this non-standard and non-portable extension to `UPDATE` command, standard command is also supported by H2 and some other database systems.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html

https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#merge_using

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tryed adding it to utl but still have the same issue, spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:deal-data-service-mem;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;

Comment: If you use H2 for unit tests you also need to disable their automatic configuration, otherwise your datasource will be ignored by Spring.

Comment: You can add `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` annotation, for example.

Comment: i don't have an EnableAutoConfiguration enabled in the project, i'm trying with merge, maybe it will work, Than you a lot @Evgenij, let you knew if it will work

Comment: Thank you it's working now, with mode=PostgresSQL, i tested in h2 console and it's working now, will see how to edit the java code then